# Log out of Twitter account on another device

Tags: twitter, privacy, passwords

My Twitter  was logged in on  my iPad before and I  forgot to log out. Since  it  is now  confiscated due  to  some issues,  I  wasn't  able  to  log  out from that  device. What  can I  do  to log  out my account  there? I  am  using my  laptop  to  access  it  and I  changed  my  password and revoked  access but I'm still scared  and paranoid that my parents  will be  able to hack and  see  all  of  my tweets.  Is changing my password  the way to  log  out that account there?

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://twitter.com/settings/applications where you will see all of the apps and devices currently logged in. Select "Revoke Access" for the iOS app on your iPad and the account should no longer be accessible from there.